# Google Apps Script: Get First Page Footer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am writing a script that pulls form entry info and applies it onto a fancy little PO via Google Docs. Initially, I was using a general footer for the document; however, I found that a second page would generate and not be fully removed. In turn, I started using the first page footer to include info only where it was needed, and this resolved the issue. Unfortunately, I am unsure how to remove the footer now that it's in use. It's important to note, there are times when the footer is needed given certain fields are entered on the form, and other times when it can be removed. I just need to know how to remove the first page only footer, I have everything figured out beyond that.

Previously, I could run **doc.getFooter().clear();** to do the trick; now, I'm unsure.

Any ideas? Here's what I have now - it doesn't work:

```
var footer = doc.getFooter();
try {
  var firstPageFooter = footer.getParent().getChild(2).asHeaderSection();
  firstPageFooter.clear();
} catch (getFirstPageFooter) {
  Logger.log("Clearing getFirstPageFooter Failed . . . " + getFirstPageFooter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to remove the 1st-page footer using Google Apps Script.

In the current stage, even when the footers are retrieved from the Document section, 1st-page hooter cannot be identified. Because the footer ID cannot be retrieved using the Document service (DocumentApp). But, when Google Docs API is used, your goal can be achieved. In this answer, I would like to propose using Docs API. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document and save the script. And, [please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var footer = doc.getFooter();
  var docId = doc.getId();
  var { documentStyle: { firstPageFooterId } } = Docs.Documents.get(docId);
  if (!firstPageFooterId && !footer) {
    console.log("No footers.");
    return;
  } else if (!firstPageFooterId && footer) {
    footer.clear();
    return;
  }
  var requests = [{ deleteFooter: { footerId: firstPageFooterId } }];
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docId);
}
```

- When this script is run, when the 1st-page footer is set, the 1st-page footer is removed.
- When the 1st-page footer is not set, the current footer is removed.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteFooterRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#deletefooterrequest)